DAX Formula to replace nested if statement on measures
I have 2 measure where it needs to have two conditions as it will apply a different if statement

if measure 1 is more than 0, the formula should be If('Measure1' > 'Measure2', "Narrow", "Widen")
If measure 1 is less than 0, the formula should be If('Measure1'<'Measure2',"Widen","Narrow")

How could I put this into the PowerBI Dax formula?

The simplest way would be do to it using a SWITCH so it easily readible and easy to change but I'm sure it could be written in a more compact format as well.
Measure =
    SWITCH(TRUE(),
    [Measure1]>0,if([Measure1]>[Measure2],"Narrow","Widen"),
    [Measure1]<0,if([Measure1]<[Measure2],"Widen","Narror")

Another way:
Measure = 
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        [Measure1] > 0 && [Measure1] > [Measure2], "Narrow",
        [Measure1] > 0 && [Measure1] <= [Measure2], "Widen",
        [Measure1] < 0 && [Measure1] < [Measure2], "Widen",
        [Measure1] < 0 && [Measure1] >= [Measure2], "Narrow"
    )

This also would work I think, if I got the logic right but it's just an example how not to do it (would still work I think):
Measure = 
    IF(
        [Measure1] * [Measure2] > 0, 
        IF(ABS([Measure1]) > ABS([Measure2]), "Narrow", "Widen"), 
        IF([Measure1] > 0, "Narrow", "Widen")
    )

And just for fun:
Measure = 
    IF(
        RANKX(UNION(ROW("Value", [Measure1]), ROW("Value", [Measure2])), [Measure1]) = 1,
        IF([Measure1] > 0, "Narrow", "Widen"),
        IF([Measure1] < 0, "Widen", "Narrow")
    )


Michal, the first works easily! I was figuring the formula and didn't know you can put a if in the switch true funciton
